# Mongoose Get full list of users in table

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I got all users details to use if and for loop from MongoDB database. but I want to all details in a HTML table so how to do that?

I got all details in this method but how to get in HTML table?

```
<h3>My users IDs are: </h3>
<ul>
 <% if (typeof usersArray !== 'undefined' && usersArray.length > 0) {%> 
 <%for (var i = 0; i < usersArray.length; i++) { %> 
 <li>ID: <%= usersArray[i]._id %></li>
 <li>Name: <%= usersArray[i]. username%></li>
 <li>District: <%= usersArray[i].country %></li> 
 <li>Email: <%= usersArray[i].email %></li> <%}%> <% } %> 
</ul>
```

my output here.........

My users IDs are:

```
ID: 59cfa3b978755b0f0b65c7ba
Name: aaa
District: Colombo
Email: aaaa
ID: 59d0310009825f1da033945b
Name: sss
District: Kalutara
Email: sss
ID: 59d03d61a2a9c620e5d458af
Name: eee
District: Kalutara
Email: eee
ID: 59d0435942e41522bdfc759d
Name: Mayoorika
District: Kalutara
Email: mayoorikarajee10@gmail.com
ID: 59d043c33d781124d4ef4239
Name: qqq
District: Kalutara
Email: qqq
```

Comment: I got all details in this method  but how to get in HTML table?.........................<h3>My users IDs are: </h3>
    <ul>
      <% if (typeof usersArray !== 'undefined' && usersArray.length > 0) {%>

        <%for (var i = 0; i < usersArray.length; i++) { %>
          <li>ID: <%= usersArray[i]._id %></li>
          <li>Name: <%= usersArray[i]. username%></li>
          <li>District: <%= usersArray[i].country %></li>
          <li>Email: <%= usersArray[i].email %></li>
        <%}%>
      <% } %>
  </ul>

Comment: Edit your question above with your HTML but also code where you query the database.

Comment: you can use express js to render data to html ejs view

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express, it supports pug templates.
You can do as follows:

1. Fetch the usersList

   `app.get('/users', function(req, res) { 
       // Get users from MongoDB and store it in usersList 
       res.render('index', {"usersList": usersList});
   }`
2. index.pug in /views/users

> ```
> table
>      for user in usersList
>             tr
>                 td= user.id
>                 td= user.name
>                 td= user.district
>                 td= user.email
> ```